# Proving $\left( A + \frac{t}{x}N \right)^x \le \left( A + \frac{s}{y}N \right)^y $

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, logarithms, convex-optimization

I want to show that

$$\left( A + \frac{t}{x}N \right)^x \le \left( A + \frac{s}{y}N \right)^y  $$

or equivalently

$$x\ln\left( A + \frac{t}{x}N \right) \le  y\ln\left( A + \frac{s}{y}N \right)$$

We know that $x < y$ and $t+x = T$ where $T$ is a known constant. Also $s+y < T$, all the parameters and variables are non-negative.

I tried to optimize the function $f(x) = x\ln\left( A + \frac{T-x}{x}N \right)$ to show it's maximum value is always less than right hand side, but the solution to stationary points is not solvable, in other words

$$f'(x) = \ln\left( A + \frac{T-x}{x}N \right) - \frac{\frac{T}{x}N}{A + \frac{T-x}{x}N} = 0$$ has no closed form solution for $x$. How should I proceed in comparing these two? Is my approach correct? Is there another way? (BTW if this helps, $f(x)$ is convex).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check it numerically?

Comment: I did plot them with MATLAB and left is less than right, but maybe my range of numbers make it true, and not in general if that's what you mean. So I should ask is this inequality true in general?

Comment: I think it is not true in general. What's the range of $A, N, T$?

Comment: $A,N$ are random variables, $N \in [1000,5000]$ and $A \in [100,600]$ are typical range for those parameters, $T = 0.1$ is deterministic. In each snapshot, I assume we completely know $A,N$ and thus we get the deterministic inequality above.

Comment: This is a very specific case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303206/finding-conditions-under-which-an-inequality-holds-true). I tried to simplify the former as much as possible and consider single case and arrived at this inequality.

Comment: Please check $A = 5000, N = 600, T = 1/10, x = 9/340, y = 2/75, t = 5/68, s = 1/100$.

Comment: That is a legit counterexample. River Li, Thank you! So, back to square one, I have to find other ways for original problem (0___0')

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f'(x) = \log\left( A + \frac{T-x}{x}N \right) - \frac{\frac{T}{x}N}{A + \frac{T-x}{x}N} = 0$$

Let $$ A + \frac{T-x}{x}N=z \implies \frac{A-N-z+z \log (z)}{z}=0$$ and the solution is given in terms of Lambert function
$$z=\frac{N-A}{W\left(\frac{N-A}{e}\right)}\implies x=\frac{N\, T\, W\left(\frac{N-A}{e}\right)}{(N-A)
   \left(1+W\left(\frac{N-A}{e}\right)\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you for heads up and answer, but I think I calculated correctly $\frac{d}{dx}\left( x\ln\left( A + \frac{T-x}{x}N \right) \right) = \ln\left( A + \frac{T-x}{x}N \right) + x\times  \frac{d}{dx}\left( \ln\left( A + \frac{T-x}{x}N \right) \right) = \ln\left( A + \frac{T-x}{x}N \right)  + x\times \frac{\frac{-T}{x^2}N}{A + \frac{T-x}{x}N}$
BTW, If the answer can be determined in terms of Lambert-W, how can I compare LHS with RHS with the solution? Thanks a lot for Hint.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald. You are correct but my result stays the same. Cheers and sorry !

Comment: Claude Leibovici, thank you for the answer, can you please explain how I use it to compare RHS with LHS? My main question was with regard to inequality I'm am trying to solve.